# In Marshmallow broadcast is not working with action android.intent.action.proximity_sensor

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, gear-vr

In Marshmallow this code is not working with GearVR. `Activity.onResume()` code

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.proximity_sensor"); 
mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { 
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

   if(intent.getType().equals("1")) 
   { 
      Log.v(LOGTAG,"headset mounted"); 
   } 
   else 
   { 
      Log.v(LOGTAG,"headset unmounted"); 
   } 

 } 
}; 

 this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter); 
}
```

this is used to detect GearVR mounted and unmounted.
It was working in S6 Lollipop.

Probably this is bug in Marshmallow 6.0.1 [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/oqh-V37hgDM).
Any workaround this problem? related links [link1](https://forums.oculus.com/vip/discussion/23927/onhead-detection-sensor) [link2](https://forums.oculus.com/developer/discussion/29091/i-cant-detect-if-the-device-is-docked-or-mounted)

Please share anything that help me in detecting GearVr mount and unmount

Comment: It may work during debugging and when your device connected to charging point.

Answer (score 0):

Android 6.0 is now using Doze mode to minimize the use of battery. So this Doze mode not allows the system wakups again and again. There should me Minimum of 9 mins gap should be there between two consecutive wakeups. See official documentation for detail.[Cleck here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

Comment: This is not what I need. I am wrote this code in activity